# Should I use a tfidf corpus or just corpus to inference documents using LDA?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I am wondering whether it's either a TFIDF corpus to be used or just corpus to be used when we are inference documents using LDA in gensim

Here is an example

```
from gensim import corpora, models
import numpy.random
numpy.random.seed(10)

doc0 = [(0, 1), (1, 1)]
doc1 = [(0,1)] 
doc2 = [(0, 1), (1, 1)]
doc3 = [(0, 3), (1, 1)]

corpus = [doc0,doc1,doc2,doc3]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(corpus)

tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]
corpus_tfidf.save('x.corpus_tfidf')

corpus_tfidf = corpora.MmCorpus.load('x.corpus_tfidf')

lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)

#which one i should use from this   
**corpus_lda = lda[corpus]**          #this one 
**corpus_LDA = lda[corpus_tfidf ]**   #or this one?


corpus_lda.save('x.corpus_lda')

for i,j in enumerate(corpus_lda):
    print j, corpus[i]
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [Gensim's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gensim/lda$20tfidf/gensim/OESG1jcaXaQ/fGNhYSVcpYUJ) (last post in particular) the standard procedure would be to use a bag of words corpus. You can use a TF-IDF corpus, but it seems to be unclear what kind of effect this would have.